# how to select group having without actualy grouping items

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I have a table that is set up in this way:

```
doc product
a   2
a   1
a   1
b   1
c   3
c   2
d   1
```

I need to select all items that share the same doc id that ordered product 1, but without actually grouping all items in doc.

so the end result should look something like this:

```
doc product
a   2
a   1
a   1
b   1
d   1
```

is there a way of achieving this type of selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE doc IN (SELECT DISTINCT doc FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE product = 1)
```

and pure BigQuery specific option (for fun and learning):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT doc, product 
FROM (
  SELECT doc, ARRAY_AGG(product) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY doc
  HAVING 1 IN UNNEST(arr)
) t, t.arr product
```

Comment: last time I was down-voted was quite a long ago. trying to figure out what this down-vote exactly for o( would be great to know

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you don't want to use a normal join or subquery here?

Something like the below:

```
Select * from table where doc in (
  select doc from table where product = 1
) t1 ;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE doc IN (
    SELECT doc
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE product = 1)
```

The subquery finds all the docs that ordered product 1. The main query then finds all the rows with those docs.

or

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT doc
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE product = 1) AS t2
ON t1.doc = t2.doc
```

`DISTINCT` is needed to prevent duplicating all the rows by the number of times that `doc` is returned by the subquery.

if the table is large I recommend the second methos, as MySQL has some notorious performance problems with `WHERE xxx IN (subquery)` queries.